# Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL' - Angular:

Tags: angular, typescript, google-chrome

Chrome Version: Version 78.0.3904.70 (Official Build) (64-bit)

So i am aware that URL.createObject URL is has been deprecated since Chrome 71, but am only just now facing the error.

Below is a snippet from my pre-loading media function where i use URL.createObject

```
// Loads a file from the server into cache
private loadFile(media: File) {
  console.log('Entered MediaModel loadFIle');

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var error: boolean = false;

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', media.url);
        request.responseType = 'blob';

        // When the request loads, check whether it was successful
        request.onload = () => {
            if (request.status === 200) {
                resolve(request.response);
            } else {
              // If it fails, reject the promise with a error message
              reject(Error('Media didn\'t load successfully; error code:' + request.statusText));
            }
        };


        // If an error occurs
        request.onerror = () => {
            reject(Error('There was a network error.'));
        };


        request.onreadystatechange = () => {
            if (request.readyState === 4) {

                media.blob = URL.createObjectURL(request.response);
                media.sanitizedBlob = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(URL.createObjectURL(request.response));

                console.log(media);
                console.log(media.blob);
                console.log(media.sanitizedBlob);
            }
        };


        // Every tick of the progress loader
        request.onprogress = data => {
            media.loadProgress = parseInt((data.loaded / data.total * 100).toFixed(0));
        }

        // Send the request
        request.send();
    });
}
```

[image: Screenshot of console.logs]

I thought i could just wrap it all in a try catch block but then I'm thinking the media won't pre-load.

A few posts/forums i have read suggest using `MediaStream` however I'm just not clear on what to replace or modify to not only remove the error but keep functionality relatively the same.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if you need more information please just let me know. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think you need to create a blob first and depending on what kind of data you have, you need to specify correct mime type. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: @Townsheriff I thought i was already creating a blob, please see edits :)

Comment: Try: `media.blob = request.response` and then you will have to find your references to `media.blob.src` and change them to `media.blob.srcObject`